# How would you implement this navigation using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Navigation
[image]

Nav w/ Hover State

[image]

How would you implement this navigation using HTML and CSS?

The white box is a placeholder for a logo.

PS: The "Products" link is a drop down menu.

My current implementation below. (Not complete)

```css
#mainNav {
  height: 60px;
  background: url(../../images/main-nav-left.png) top left no-repeat, url(../../images/main-nav-right.png) top right no-repeat, url(../../images/main-nav-repeat.png) top repeat-x;
}
#mainNav li {
  float: left;
  height: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#mainNav li:not(.logo-wrapper) {
  padding: 0px 47px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#mainNav li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#mainNav li.logo-wrapper {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#mainNav h1 {
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="thirteen columns" id="mainNav">
  <ul>
    <li class="logo-wrapper">
      <h1 id="logo">
         <%= link_to image_tag('logo.png'), root_path %>
       </h1>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Parts</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Resources</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My main problem is figuring out how to get the slanted separators and the right end of the nav working with the hover states.

Comment: Which browsers/versions do you need to support? IE7? IE8?

Comment: Preferably IE8. webkit/FF4 would work though

Comment: what is your problem with separators? you can add a class to LI element and apply background to them. As for hovering, I would suggest using sprites.

Comment: that wont' work because the background in the hover states interfere with each other because of the slants

Answer (score 2):

Well first things first, I would learn about both of those technologies, and also jQuery to cover the drop down portion.  I suggest starting here:

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/
- http://www.alistapart.com/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html
- http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page
- http://htmldog.com/
- http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/

As for specific implementation to answer that question broadly would take a lot of effort.  Are you asking about how to handle something in particular?  What HTML structures you would use?  Are you trying to do the eye candy using pure CSS?  Etc.

---

**Update:**
Thanks for editing -- I'll revise shortly

Comment: I already have started to implement this. I am interested in how others would go about it.

Comment: As it stands your question is essentially "please do my work for me?" -- get more specific and I'll be happy to update my answer.

Comment: My main problem is figuring out how to get the slanted separators and the right end of the nav working with the hover states. And no I am not using pure CSS because I cannot figure out an elegant solution for the slants with pure css.